# Trying to search an array against another array, with other array having internal priority

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`ic` is my input array and `cbList` is my internal array that im checking agaist. I want to check the whole array and return the highest value in based on the `cbList`. I have some ugly code already tried but i dont want to use it, can someone basically make this better and more efficient. I've been searching and cant find anything in my situation.

So basically just want to check `ic` and if *highest* pops up, break out and return that value, if no *highest* is found, then go on to check *high* value, and so on...

```
            function hcbin(inv){
            var fh;
            var ic = ['low','med','low','high'];
            var cbList = [ 'low', 'med', 'high','highest'];


            for( var i = 0; i < ic.length; i++) {
                if (ic[i] === cbList[3]) {
                    $scope.hdc = ic[i];
                    fh = true;
                }
            }

            if (!fh){
                for( var ii = 0; ii < ic.length; ii++) {
                    if (ic[ii] === cbList[2]) {
                        $scope.hdc = ic[ii];
                        fh = true;
                    }
                }
            }

             if (!fh){
                 for( var iii = 0; iii < ic.length; iii++) {
                     if (ic[iii] === cbList[1]) {
                         $scope.hdc = ic[iii];
                         fh = true;
                     }
                 }
             }

             if (!fh){
                 for( var iiii = 0; iiii < ic.length; iiii++) {
                     if (ic[iiii] === cbList[0]) {
                         $scope.hdc = ic[iiii];
                         fh = true;
                     }
                 }
             }
        };
```

Comment: Please change var names so they make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```js
var ic = ['low','med','low', 'high'];
var cbList = [ 'low', 'med', 'high','highest'];
var result = null;

for (var i = (cbList.length - 1); i >=0; i--) {
  if (ic.indexOf(cbList[i]) > -1) {
    result = cbList[i];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Make sure `cbList` keeps the priority order(from *low* to *highest* importance) because the `for` is based upon that.

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm, dont have enough rep to vote up :/

Comment: @KyleSilk now you have! hahaha

Comment: @KyleSilk nice, glad to help!